# How to cypher / uncypher binary data from PHP to Dart / flutter in AES256

Tags: php, flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I want to cypher / uncypher binary data from PHP to Dart (and dart to PHP) in AES256.
My code is working for text data, but not for binary data. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

- In the code below, if you uncomment //text="hello", the cypher text is the same, and also uncyphered : it works!.
- If I keep the comment, so working with binary data : for l_group_id variable, cyphered text is not the same in php and dart (and so the uncyphered result)

Here is my code :

PHP :

```
$_key = 'MySecretKeyForEncryptionAndDecry'; // 32 chars
$_iv = 'helloworldhelloW'; // 16 chars
$_method = 'aes-256-cbc';


$l_group_id = 1540980342;
$text = pack ("N", $l_group_id);
echo "Cypher : ".(($l_group_id >> 24) & 0xFF)." ".(($l_group_id >> 16) & 0xFF)." ".(($l_group_id >> 8) & 0xFF)." ".(($l_group_id) & 0xFF)."<br/>";

//$text = "hello";

$msg1 = openssl_encrypt($text, $_method, $_key, 0, $_iv);
$msg2 = openssl_decrypt($msg1, $_method, $_key, 0, $_iv);

echo "Cypher text : $msg1<br>";
echo "UnCypher text : $msg2<br/>";
```

Dart :

```
var key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('MySecretKeyForEncryptionAndDecry'); //32 chars
var iv = IV.fromUtf8('helloworldhelloW'); //16 chars

int l_group_id = 1540980342;
Uint8List tab = new Uint8List (13);
tab[0] = ((l_group_id >> 24) & 0xFF);
tab[1] = ((l_group_id >> 16) & 0xFF);
tab[2] = ((l_group_id >> 8) & 0xFF);
tab[3] = ((l_group_id & 0xFF));

String text = String.fromCharCodes(tab);

//text = "hello";

// encrypt
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
String msg1 = encrypted.base64;

// decrypt
final msg2 = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(msg1), iv: iv);

debugPrint("msg1 : $msg1 - msg2 : $msg2");
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If encrypting `tab` you should be using `encryptBytes` https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypter/encryptBytes.html

Comment: The `cypher` is a tag for a graph query language. I suspect you meant to use `cipher` (or one of the specific cipher tags). There is also a more generic `encryption` tag.

Comment: Thank you Richard, that was so simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary length seems to be incorrect (13 vs 4). It's easier to use `ByteData` too.

```
  final lGroupId = 1540980342;
  // php pack N => 32 bit unsigned big endian => 4 bytes
  // the 3rd parameter is optional - the default *is* big
  final lGroupIdBytes = Uint8List(4)
    ..buffer.asByteData().setUint32(0, lGroupId, Endian.big);

  print(lGroupIdBytes); // should match the values from PHP

  // now use encrypter.encryptBytes(lGroupIdBytes, iv: iv);
  // this assumes the encrypter defaults to PKCS7 padding
```

Comment: Thank you for the asByteData, I didn't know it.

Comment: Even with this modification, I still have the same issue : 
in PHP, msg1 variable is equal to : CLLplFJScO++RCGwHhqgrg== and in Dart, msg1 variable is equal to : Nwhc9XrLz/SWJxkb37moYg== ....
Any other idea to solve my problem ?

Answer (score -1):

The solution (thank you Richard)

```
var key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('MySecretKeyForEncryptionAndDecry'); //32 chars
var iv = IV.fromUtf8('helloworldhelloW'); //16 chars

int l_group_id = 1540980342;
// php pack N => 32 bit unsigned big endian => 4 bytes
// the 3rd parameter is optional - the default *is* big
final lGroupIdBytes = Uint8List(4)
  ..buffer.asByteData().setUint32(0, l_group_id, Endian.big);

String text = String.fromCharCodes(lGroupIdBytes);

//text = "hello";

// encrypt
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
final encrypted = encrypter.encryptBytes (lGroupIdBytes, iv: iv);
String msg1 = encrypted.base64;

// decrypt
final msg2 = encrypter.decryptBytes(Encrypted.fromBase64(msg1), iv: iv);

debugPrint("msg1 : $msg1 - msg2 : $msg2");
```

Comment: You should accept mine rather than posting an alternative. Add a comment or edit mine if you needed a small change.

Comment: Done ! Sorry, first use of stack overflow...